# How to create a unique key for v-for

Tags: vue.js

please tell me how to make a unique key for v-for
For example, if you use the index as a key, then the last element will always be animated. Several elements with the same text can exist at the same time.
How can I implement this
Math.random is unlikely to be a good problem-solving solution
Can I use something like Symbol for a unique id

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="message">
    <transition-group name="msgAnimation" tag="div">
      <div v-for="(msg, i) in messages" :key="i" class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper__block" @click="messages.splice(i, 1)">
          {{ msg }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
  #message {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .msgAnimation-enter-active,
  .msgAnimation-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 1s;
  }

  .msgAnimation-enter,
  .msgAnimation-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 9vmin;
    margin: 1vmin;
  }

  .wrapper__block {
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#message',
    data: {
      messages: [
        "hi",
        "hi",
        "123321",
        "hi",
        "32112332112sdfs",
        "hi",
        "qweewq",
        "ashjdddsa",
        "asdfddsa",
        "asggghjddsa",
        "ashddsa",
        "asjghjddsa",
        "asjddsa",
        "asdddsa",
      ],
    },
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where a minimal example might not be ideal. You're right that an array index won't work as a `key` in a `<transition-group>`. The appropriate key will depend on your real data and where it comes from, though. Are your real `messages` actually just strings, or entire objects? How are they loaded/received/created?

Comment: Using Index is like using no key at all. What I would suggest is to use a prefix with the key element which in your case would be :key=`msgs_${i}` because your key can either be numeric or a string.

Comment: Messages are just strings, they are inserted using Array.prototype.push()

Comment: you can get a good amount of uniqueness if you combine Math.random() with date timestamp, like: `new Date().valueOf().toString(16) + Math.random().toString(16).substring(2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only strings you should wrap each message with object. It's more convenient way to use `id` instead of index in your case.

```js
data: {
  currentId: 0,
  messages: [
    "hi",
    "hi",
    "123321",
    "hi",
  ]
},
created: function() {
  this.messages = this.messages.map(function(message) {
    return this.wrap(message)
  })
},
methods: {
  wrap: function(msg) { // make message object with unique (not random) id.
    return {
      id: ++this.currentId,
      message: msg
    }
  },
  addMessage: function(msg) {
    this.messages.push(this.wrap(msg))
  }
}
```

Now, each new message has own unique `id`, so problem with removing message by index should gone.

Then key message by `id`:

```html
<div v-for="(msg, i) in messages" :key="msg.id" class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__block" @click="messages.splice(i, 1)">
    {{ msg.message }}
  </div>
</div>
```